# Json/Jackson naming convention

Tags: java, json, jackson

My exception class looks like this , when serialized using jackson , when i tried to deserialize it
the members were named 'message' and '**restoreStatus**' , i was expecting them to be 'message' and '**status**'.

Why did jackson choose to name my status variable as restoreStatus?How does jackson/json naming conventions work?

```
@XStreamAlias("RestoreInProgressException")
public class RestoreInProgressException extends HostManagerException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = xxxx;

    private RestoreStatus status;

    @JsonCreator
    public RestoreInProgressException(@JsonProperty("message") String message, @JsonProperty("status") RestoreStatus status) {
        super(message, HttpStatus.SC_CONFLICT);
        this.status = status;
    }

    public RestoreStatus getRestoreStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, see this question [Jackson field based serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240372/jackson-field-based-serialization) to find some information how serialization algorithm works in Jackson library. In your example you have `status` property but `getRestoreStatus` getter method. Jackson reads all getter methods from the class and tries to serialize it. Jackson will also add to the output JSON your `status` property if you annotate it with `@JsonProperty` or `@JsonProperty("status")`. In this case your output Jackson will be contains two properties `status` and `restoreStatus`. If you want to have only `status` property in your output JSON you have to:
I. Change your getter method name to `getStatus`:

```
public RestoreStatus getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}
```

II. Add annotation `@JsonProperty("status")` to your method:

```
@JsonProperty("status")
public RestoreStatus getRestoreStatus() {
    return this.status;
}
```

Comment: Correct. In this case, however, there would not be 'status', just because field is `private`, and by default only public fields (and getters) are auto-detected.